# Analytical derivation of the distribution of dependent quantities

Tags: probability, statistics

The problem I am facing is the following.
I do have two physical quantities, $x$ and $y$, and I know the analytical relation between the two

$$y = g(x)$$

Now, I know that $x$ is well represented by a random variable with probability density function $p(x)$.

Is there an analytical way to determine how the quantity $y$ is distributed? In other words, can I analytically infer $p(y)$? If yes, is it possible to generalise to multidimensional dependencies (e.g. $y = g(x, z)$ knowing $p(x)$ and $p(z)$)?

Comment: Have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function)?

Comment: Oh thank you, quite what I needed.